# wxPython Panel in existing window: slow and small

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm experiencing very different behavior when creating a wx.Panel depending on whether the main window's already called Show().

With the below code, the application opens quickly with MainPanel created & populated before `MainFrame.Show()`.  Using "New" to re-create it has multi-second lag while it re-makes the 200 texts.  Also the MainPanel doesn't expand to take up the whole size of the window until the window is resized.

This is definitely an issue with panel creation rather than panel destruction; if I remove the MainPanel creation in MainFrame's init, then the New action has the same speed & size issues.

Two questions:

Is there anything I can do to speed up panel creation after `MainFrame.Show()`?

What needs to be done when creating MainPanel after `MainFrame.Show()`ed to have the MainPanel expand to the size of its parent?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel

class MainPanel(wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.SetupScrolling()
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        for i in range(1,200):
            sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, "I'm static text"))
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.SetAutoLayout(True)

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="FrameTest", size=(600,800))
        self.InitMenu()
        self.panel = None
        self.panel = MainPanel(self)

    def InitMenu(self):
        self.menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuFile = wx.Menu()
        menuFile.Append(wx.ID_NEW, "&New")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnNew, id=wx.ID_NEW)
        self.menuBar.Append(menuFile, "&File")
        self.SetMenuBar(self.menuBar)

    def OnNew(self, evt):
        if self.panel:
            self.panel.Destroy()
        self.panel = MainPanel(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(0)
    frame = MainFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

**UPDATE**: joaquin's SendSizeEvent() definitely solves the first problem.  For the second, I've found that hiding containers works out well.  I'm guessing that after the window's been shown, it's trying to unnecessarily re-(display/layout/something) after every new widget and that's slowing it down.  If I add Hide & Show to the panel's init, then there's no more lag and it works in both situations.

```
class MainPanel(wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.SetupScrolling()
        self.Hide()
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        for i in range(1,200):
            sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, "I'm static text"))
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.SetAutoLayout(True)
        self.Show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The panel will get the correct size if the Frame feels a SizeEvent. So this works for your second question:

```
def OnNew(self, evt):
    if self.panel:
        self.panel.Destroy()
    self.panel = MainPanel(self)
    self.SendSizeEvent()
```

Control of windows and widgets becomes easier by using sizers. With sizers in your main frame you can use the sizer `Layout` method to fit widgets in place.

Could not find a way of speeding up panel rewrite. But you can diminish the bizarre visual effect by not deleting the panel but clearing the sizer instead (you dont need `SendSizeEvent()` for this case):

```
class MainPanel(wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.SetupScrolling()
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.fill()
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

    def fill(self):
        tup = [wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, "I'm static text") for i in range(200)]
        self.sizer.AddMany(tup)
        self.Layout()

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="FrameTest", size=(600,800))
        self.InitMenu()
        self.panel = None
        self.panel = MainPanel(self)

    def InitMenu(self):
        self.menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuFile = wx.Menu()
        menuFile.Append(wx.ID_NEW, "&New")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnNew, id=wx.ID_NEW)
        self.menuBar.Append(menuFile, "&File")
        self.SetMenuBar(self.menuBar)

    def OnNew(self, evt):
        if self.panel:
            self.panel.sizer.Clear()
        self.panel.fill()
```

Comment: Clearing the sizer rather than deleting is interesting, although it doesn't help with my real-life scenario.  I have an empty window and create a panel when the user opens a file, so there's no previous panel to "not delete".  I've found Hide()ing and Show()ing help out, though, as I've updated the question.  Thanks!